# How to combine features of different types more effectively with python

Tags: python, algorithm, sqlite, nlp, svm

I am doing a text classification task(7000 texts evenly distributed by 10 labels). I set character, word and POS as colume names and stored all characters words and POS tags of each text into `Sqlite3` database. What I want to do is to combine character 2-gram, word 2-gram and POS 2-gram into a training vector for `SVM`. My code is below:

```
def dbConnect(db_name,sql):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    n = cursor.execute(sql)
    res1 = cursor.fetchall()
    return res1

def createtrainingVector(item,n,count1,res1):
        ''' append all items(character/word/POS n-gram) that occurs at least count1 times in the text into a training Vector used for SVM'''

def featureComb(item,count1,res1):
    '''combine features into a vector'''
    if item == "word":
        train_vector1 = createtrainingVector(item,1,count1,res1)
        train_vector2 = createtrainingVector(item,2,count1,res1)
    elif item == "character":
        train_vector1 = createtrainingVector(item,1,count1,res1)
        train_vector2 = createtrainingVector(item,2,count1,res1)
    elif item == "pos":
        train_vector1 = createtrainingVector(item,1,count1,res1)
        train_vector2 = createtrainingVector(item,2,count1,res1)
    return sorted(train_vector1+train_vector2)

def svmParaComb(item,train_vector,label_vector,X,y,res1):
    matrix = []
    for res in res1:            
        y.append(label_vector[res[0]])

        if item == "word":
            word_dic1 = wordNgrams(res[1], 1)
            word_dic2 = wordNgrams(res[1], 2)
        elif lexical == "pos":
            word_dic1 = lemmaNgrams(json.loads(res[1]), 1)
            word_dic2 = lemmaNgrams(json.loads(res[1]), 2)
        elif lexical == "character":
            word_dic1 = characterNgrams(res[1], 1)
            word_dic2 = characterNgrams(res[1], 2)
        X.append([1 if gram in (word_dic1 or word_dic2) else 0 for gram in train_vecter)

db = 'text.db'
'''Access to database and Extract label and essay'''
sql_dict1 = {"word": "select label,word from main.training_data",
        "pos" : "select label,pos from main.training_data",
        "character" : "select label,character from main.training_data",
        }
sql_dict2 = {"word": "select label,word from main.test_data",
        "pos" : "select label,pos from main.test_data", 
        "character" : "select label,character from main.test_data",
        }

if i == 1:
        sql1 = sql_dict1["word"]
        sql2 = sql_dict2["word"]
elif i == 2:
        sql1 = sql_dict1["character"]
        sql2 = sql_dict2["character"]
elif i == 3:
        sql1 = sql_dict1["pos"]
        sql2 = sql_dict2["pos"]
res1 = dbConnect(db, sql1)
    X = []
    y = []
    train_vector_combine = featureComb(item, 2,res1)
    svmParaComb(item, train_vector_combine, label_vector, X, y, res1)

    clf1 = svm.LinearSVC()
    clf1.fit(X, y)

    res2 = dbConnect(db, sql2)

    '''Parameter used for predicting'''
    X_test = []
    y_true = []
    svmCombinePredict(item, train_vector, label_vector, X_test, y_true, res2)  

    clf1.predict(X_test)
    print clf1.score(X_test,y_true)
```

However, it can only combine features of the same type. I do not know how to deal with the combination of different types features, because res1 represents only one colume word/character/POS. therefore, if I want to combine character 2-gram, word 2-gram and POS 2-gram into a training vector, what should I do? Could anyone help me with my code?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want the SVM to distinguish between 1-grams, 2-grams, etc?

If this is your only problem, why don't you just prefix your tokens with something that allows you to distinguish them? Your tokens are strings, right?

Comment: @pi. Thanks for your reply. However, what I want to do is to combine features of different types, such as character 2-gram, word 2-gram and POS 2-gram. My code only works for feature combination of same types,such as word 1-gram and word 2-gram. therefore, My question is how to correct my code to deal with feature combination of different types?

Comment: Use featureunion in scikit